# using netty library, server unable to handle the reconnection scenario of client

Tags: java, netty

Initially able to make the connection. Simply close the connection client and try to connect again or restart the client. the connection is not established. It creates connection only once.
Can someone help me to improve it. So, it can handle n number client simultaneously.

```
bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
    workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();



    b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 100)
            .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO)).childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                    p.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(20000, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
                    // p.addLast(new StringDecoder());
                    // p.addLast(new StringEncoder());

                    p.addLast(serverHandler);
                }
            });

    // Start the server.
    LOGGER.key("Simulator is opening listen port").low().end();
    ChannelFuture f = b.bind(config.getPort()).sync();
    LOGGER.key("Simulator started listening at port: " + config.getPort()).low().end();


    // Wait until the server socket is closed.
    f.channel().closeFuture().sync();

} finally {
    // Shut down all event loops to terminate all threads.
    LOGGER.key("Shtting down all the thread if anyone is still open.").low().end();
    bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
}
```

Server Handler code is below:

```
    public class SimulatorServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {

    private AtomicReference<ChannelHandlerContext> ctxRef = new AtomicReference<ChannelHandlerContext>();
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    private AtomicInteger seqNum = new AtomicInteger(1);
    private final Configuration configure;

    private ScheduledFuture<?> hbTimerWorker;


    private final int stx = 0x02;
    private final int etx = 0x03;
    private final ILogger LOGGER;
    public int enablePublishFunction = 0;

    public SimulatorServerHandler(Configuration config) {
        this.configure = config;
        //LOGGER = LogFactory.INSTANCE.createLogger();
        LOGGER = new LogFactory().createLogger("SIM SERVER");

    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ctxRef.set(ctx);
        enablePublishFunction =1;
//      System.out.println("Connected!");
        LOGGER.low().key("Gateway connected to the Simulator ").end();
        startHBTimer();

    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ctx.fireChannelInactive();
        hbTimerWorker.cancel(false);
        enablePublishFunction =0;
        LOGGER.low().key("Gateway disconnected from the Simulator ").end();
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String request) {
        // Generate and write a response.
        String response;
        boolean close = false;
 /*       if (request.isEmpty()) {
            response = "Please type something.\r\n";
        } else if ("bye".equals(request.toLowerCase())) {
            response = "Have a good day!\r\n";
            close = true;
        } else {
            response = "Did you say '" + request + "'?\r\n";
        }

        // We do not need to write a ChannelBuffer here.
        // We know the encoder inserted at TelnetPipelineFactory will do the conversion.
        ChannelFuture future = ctx.write(response);

        // Close the connection after sending 'Have a good day!'
        // if the client has sent 'bye'.
        if (close) {
            future.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        }
        */
        System.out.println(request);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        LOGGER.key("Unknown exception while network communication :"+ cause.getStackTrace()).high().end();
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you use always the very same server handler in your pipeline for all connections (not using new ServerHandler())? Side effects in your implementation could block your handler to be reusable.